# TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable with mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql

```
def displayResult(self):
    name = input("> ")
    self.cursor.execute("SELECT username FROM customer Where username = '%s' " % name)
    if name in self.cursor.fetchone():
        print("flag")
    elif name not in self.cursor.fetchone():
        print("Not in here.")
    elif name == "" or name == " ":
        print("Input something.")
```

I try to made function to use for : When user input any username if user name it had in database it will print 'flag', and if not in database or user not input anything it will "print not in here",
So when i run this code and try to input some what username it's not in datbase and try to leave them with blank space, i found this error

```
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

How can i shut this error warning

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing a check on the return value of `fetchone` before trying to iterate it, e.g.:

```
one = self.cursor.fetchone()
if one is not None:
    if name in one:
        print("flag")
    # etc
```

Comment: I got this, Thanks but i still not understand, Why self.cursor.fetchone() value is None ?

Comment: [This method retrieves the next row of a query result set and returns a single sequence, or None if no more rows are available.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html).